# OpenCart outgoing email fails DMARC Evaluation

Tags: email, joomla, opencart, dmarc

I am supporting a site that uses OpenCart but hasn't been used in a few months.  Now that the owner wants to ramp things up, naturally it's not working.

According to BlueHost, the hosting system, outgoing email are being bounced back due to the email messages failing DMARC Evaluation.

The site uses: 
OpenCart 1.5.6
Mail protocol
-F mail parameter
And multiple alert email address

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Here is the header from a rejected email:

```
Return-Path: <no-reply@evolutionsportsrivals.com>
Received: (qmail 31995 invoked by uid 0); 9 Dec 2014 22:11:55 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO cmgw2) (67.20.127.202)
     by soproxy5.unifiedlayer.com with SMTP; 9 Dec 2014 22:11:55 -0000
Received: from box530.bluehost.com ([74.220.219.130])
     by cmgw2 with
     id RaBq1p00K2pQ6Ly01aBtBH; Tue, 09 Dec 2014 15:11:55 -0700
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.1 cv=Hd2HEE08 c=1 sm=1 tr=0
     a=MltV6XJxWvsVI5oZWfFRnA==:117 a=MltV6XJxWvsVI5oZWfFRnA==:17 a=cNaOj0WVAAAA:8
     a=f5113yIGAAAA:8 a=slmv76GBlJ4A:10 a=aXg1NtKh9PcA:10 a=3oc9M9_CAAAA:8
     a=kuuYk_0VAAAA:8 a=dbGbKXWtDu8A:10 a=A92cGCtB03wA:10 a=DTyR1oDw6keH4Tl_xgIA:9
     a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=uDuEJxyF-qUA:10 a=iobJmb39UvMA:10 a=XYoNdVabuq8A:10
     a=kZ36JB5Pai94E--oucIA:9 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=LK_T0k1tTYcA:10
     a=kNc_wxIRdnEA:10 a=2rOyub8MfPoA:10 a=cKwDkCc9V9MA:10
Received: from evoluty5 by box530.bluehost.com with local (Exim 4.82)
     (envelope-from <no-reply@evolutionsportsrivals.com>)
     id 1XyT0Y-0001aZ-2N
     for martin.fritch@comcast.net; Tue, 09 Dec 2014 15:11:50 -0700
To: martin.fritch@comcast.net
Subject: test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 2029:mail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 15:11:49 -0700
From: Evolution Sports Rivals<Odie77r@aol.com>
Reply-To: Evolution Sports Rivals<Odie77r@aol.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.34
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_d9b504fb1fa0ce6faecdab3c8a280b6b"
Message-Id: <E1XyT0Y-0001aZ-2N@box530.bluehost.com>
X-Identified-User: {2029:box530.bluehost.com:evoluty5:evolutionsportsrivals.com} {sentby:program running on server, non-smtp}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work!!

If anyone else is running into this issue or something simular, here is what I found.

Using Mail or SMTP for the Mail Protocol made no difference that I could see.  I went with Mail since that is what OpenCart recommeneded.

I used the -F Mail Parameter, but didn't fully test if this had to be set or not.  I was just so glad that it worked, I left it in.

The final piece of the puzzle for me was that the E-mail setting under the General Tab was using an AOL account.  With the new DMARC Evaluation, I think this has to have an email account that shares the same domain as the website.

So....
I set up an email for the store owner with his site domain,
Set the Store email to the new email account,
Set the -F Mail Parameter to the new email account